# Range of dynamic ip to static ip

Tags: dns, ip-address

We have a salesforce.com application for a product (autoparts) catalog.

The data vendor allows us to reach their server to get the product's info and picture
only from one static ip (we can tell them which one).

The problem is that when our application tries to reach the vendor server, it does it
from an ip of an ip range used by salesforce.com server farms. So we can't reach them as the ip is not static (it is a different each time).

How can we have a solution that in one side listens to all the ips within a 
specified range and then transparently routes the xml commands back and
forth with a single fixed ip reaching the data vendor?